# Appengine Mapreduce Restricted Class ManagementFactory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I get a restricted class exception when I trigger a mapreduce job using Appengine-mapreduce library.I am using appengine sdk version 1.8.8. Error seems to be because of hadoop-0.20.2 internally used by appengine-mapper code.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.<clinit>(ManagementFactory.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.<clinit>(ReflectionUtils.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.add(SerializationFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.<init>(SerializationFactory.java:54)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.SerializationUtil.serializeToByteArrayOutputStream(SerializationUtil.java:46)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.SerializationUtil.serializeToByteArray(SerializationUtil.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.v2.impl.ShardState.setInputSplit(ShardState.java:215)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.v2.impl.handlers.Worker.scheduleShards(Worker.java:218)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.mapreduce.v2.impl.handlers.Controller.handleStart(Controller.java:133)
```

Triggering Code:

```
MapReduceXml mrXml = MapReduceXml.getMapReduceXmlFromFile();
Configuration configuration = mrXml.instantiateConfiguration( configName, params );

jobId = Controller.handleStart(configuration, configName, "/mapreduce/");
```

Please advise!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got resolved, after using the hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar shipped along with appengine-mapper. It doesnt seem to like hadoop-core-0.20.2 file from maven.